# How to swap images on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The footer has icons on click. I want to swap images with the header image, it will be helpful if I get any suggestions.

Have a look [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/babuharry/dLh9nvho/)

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/q.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>

    <!-- codepen - your codepen profile-->
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/q1.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>

    <!-- codepen - your codepen profile-->
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/f.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>

    <!-- codepen - your codepen profile-->
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/q2.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean `swap`?

Comment: add an event to onClick in the footer images and swap the src of header img with the clicked image.

Comment: there are many, many questions on Stack Overflow which answer your question already.  Search for 'jquery image swap' and read up.

Comment: Hi @Mr_Perfect , i mean on click exchange images on both sides, there are images on footer, and also one image in header, on lick footer image footer image and header image exchange their places

Comment: okay i will google again

Comment: when i click the bottom [first] image the top image swaps source as-is https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/4ojL66dg/ but the bottom image stays the same (but i set the image source to be the same for top and bottom)

Comment: yea i get it thanks for your time @RachelGallen

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample snippet.

```
$(img).on('click', function(e)
{
   $("#iq").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
})
```

This code will react on every image you click however, it should be self explanatory how to get the desired functionality from here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for swapping the image clicked in the footer with the header image every time you click any of the footer images.

```
$('ul img').click(function(){

    var header_src = $('header img').attr('src');

    $("header img").attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    $(this).attr('src', header_src);

});
```

Comment: Hi Raj it's working thanks a lot, yea i understand now how it's working so i can use this in different ways